# How is the loss function in Tensorflow called? Problems with custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I do have a siamese network written in Tensorflow Keras that outputs a probability that measures how close two samples are.

```
original_model.predict([sample1, sample2, ...])=[probability1, probability2 ...] = y_predctions
```

where each sample contains the information of two samples.
I used binary cross entropy as a loss function with a given y_true vector that contains the real outcome of the sample. 1 if the two samples are a match and 0 otherwise.

Now I redesigned the model that the model predictions are a matrix that contains information about all pairwise combination of the samples:

```
model.predict([sample1, sample2, ...])=[[probability11, probability12 ...] [probability21, probability22 ...] ... ] = y_predictions
```

However my y_true vector is still one dimensional.

I wrote a loss function that takes y_true and y_predictions as an input and calculates a loss. This works well if y_true and y_predictions are a numpy array.

I can compile the model and make predictions and also evaluate the model but I cannot fit my model (model.fit(x_train, y_true))

Is there a way to use a loss function that takes a one-dimensional NumPy array as y_true and a n x n NumPy matrix as y_pred?
And more in general how is the loss function called in Tensorflow?

- I know that the parameters that are given to the loss function are not the same as the predicted output. I modified the loss function that it takes not model.predict(x_train) as an input but model(x_train). (I just converted y_pred with y_pred.numpy()). When I tried to fit the model I get the error 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'.
  Although I am using tf version 2.0 I made sure that tf.enable_eager_execution() is executed at the beginning.
  I printed the y_pred vector inside the loss function and got the following:

  print(y_pred)
  Tensor("layer_name/Identity:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)
- I also tried to use the [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) module that wraps a numpy function in a tf function. When I tried to fit the model I got the error *ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:*

As mentioned above I use Tensorflow 2.0 and python 3.7.6

Comment: Not clearly understand what do you want. However, you can have more freedom if you know that keras loss function may use actually any external tensors, while y_true and y_pred might be dummy variables. [Check this code for example](https://github.com/IShengFang/Relativistic-average-GAN-Keras/blob/master/RaGAN_CustomLoss.py). You can feed your custom label data then via additional Input, compute loss as you want.